# Can I test for the existence of a Plone page directly in a Diazo rule?

Tags: plone, diazo

I've written a Diazo rule that allows users to customize the footer of their Plone site by editing a specific page within the site.  The following rule does what I want:

```
<replace css:theme-children="#portal-footer"
  css:content-children="#content-core"
  href="/theme_resources/footer"
  if="$footer_id = 'footer'" />
```

with the following parameter expression in the advanced settings:

```
footer_id = context/theme_resources/footer/id | nothing
```

If I don't include the condition, when the user deletes or moves /theme_resources/footer I get the following traceback and the theme isn't applied at all:

```
2013-05-28 10:46:55 ERROR plone.subrequest Error handling subrequest to /theme_resources/footer
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\plone43\eggs\plone.subrequest-1.6.7-py2.7.egg\plone\subrequest\__init__.py", line 116, in subrequest
    traversed = request.traverse(path)
  File "c:\plone43\eggs\zope2-2.13.19-py2.7.egg\ZPublisher\BaseRequest.py", line 518, in traverse
    return response.notFoundError(URL)
  File "c:\plone43\eggs\zope2-2.13.19-py2.7.egg\ZPublisher\HTTPResponse.py", line 718, in notFoundError
```

When I include the condition, the theme breaks if the user deletes the parameter expression.

Is there a different condition I can use on the rule to test for the existence of the page directly without the variable?

Comment: An alternative way to achieve the same thing (an editable footer): Create a static text portlet to contain the footer and use diazo rules to move it to the footer position.

Answer (score 0):

You can't test for existence of arbitrary content objects directly with Diazo.

If your problem is the theme *visually* breaking when the condition evaluates to false you can use another  rule with the exact opposite condition so you can have a dynamic fallback in the Diazo layer. In this case, though, I'd simply put a static fallback footer in the HTML so it'd be used when the  rule doesn't get applied.

On the other hand, if you meant your theme isn't applied *at all* when the footer page is deleted, please post a traceback.

Comment: I added the traceback, and I clarified that the theme breaking means that it isn't applied at all.